# LSTM skews predictions towards one value

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, nlp, lstm

I am trying to train an LSTM, followed by a Dense layer in keras with numerical input sequences of different lengths. the numbers range is [1,13]. each one of those sequences ends with the same number, 13 in my case.

I train the controller on a few sequences, use the trained model to generate a few more sequences with the same properties, add them to the training set and train the LSTM again. As this loop goes on, the LSTM predictions start converging towards the final value of each sequence.

The sequences are padded to a certain maximum length. as a result the x_train data is of the size (None, max_len-1) and y_train data is categorical data of the last element of each input sequence. in this case, every element in the y_train data is the same (one hot encoded vector for the number 13).

1. Is the way input and output data is structured the reason for this skewing of predictions?
2. Is there a way to work around it?

Comment: A very important point to remember when you are trying to train a machine learning model. 

> There should be always more than one target/output/category class to be trained on.

In your case, the y_train is same throughout the data so there is nothing for the machine learning model to learn. It would be better if you can describe more about what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: yes, that's what I was going for as well. I figured I could use the second last element from the sequence instead of the last one. That would give the lstm a lot of diversity to learn from. I am also thinking of experimenting with the optimizers and their learning rates to see if i could slow down the convergence to the final value.

Comment: I am trying to find the best architecture out of all possible architectures for a neural network with only dense layers. the encoding in the sequences represents the kind of layer it is. for eg: 1 : Dense(16, activation='relu'), 2 : Dense(16, activation='sigmoid'), 3: Dense(32, activation='relu') so on and so forth. for a given dataset, the last layer is always a softmax layer with number of nodes equal to the target classes for the given dataset, in my case 10 for mnist. i am trying to train the lstm which generates such architectures in the form of sequences.

Comment: Okay, I think now I understood your point and what you are trying to do. For this problem statement, still, the approach you are taking is wrong, since you are not telling or defining a target variable which can tell lstm what is the end result of each of your architectures. so you need to create another target variable and use the output of your architectures interms of maybe accuracy range or maybe loss, it depends.

Comment: also one more important thing to notice is whether you want to create a generative model or predictive model. Both the cases will have entirely different approach. from  the way you are writing the code, it's towards a predictive model but from what you have described in the comments it also seems you want to do it the generative way.

Comment: my suggestion would be to use the predictive approach first and make a model which can predict the arcitecture you are trying to build and whether it will give good results or not. Basically a binary classifier. from there you can evolve your model and the problem statement.

Comment: you're right about the generative/predictive modelling of the problem. the approach I am taking is to make the lstm generate models, train them, extract the validation accuracy, find out if it is good enough and accordingly append said generated sequences to the lstm training data, train the lstm on these sequences and repeat.

Comment: i also found that the lstm was learning a lot better (regardless the repetitive target values) once i changed the optimizer from adam to sgd.